# C++: Errors when inserting a struct into a set

Tags: c++, struct, set

I'm trying to insert a `struct` into a `set` within an ITK class.

The struct is defined within the `class` as follows:

```
struct PixType {

    IndexType Index;
    PixelType Value;

    bool operator <(const PixType&rhs) {
        return (double)Value < (double)rhs.Value;
    }

};
```

Where `IndexType` and `PixelType` are the index and value for pixels in an image:

```
typedef typename TImage::IndexType              IndexType;
typedef typename TImage::PixelType              PixelType;
```

However, when I create my set and try to insert an element...

```
// Create set
std::set< PixType > MySet;

// Create something to insert into set
PixType LeftPixel;
LeftPixel.Index = qualIt.GetIndex( left );
LeftPixel.Value = qualIt.GetPixel( left );

// Try to insert into set
MySet.insert( LeftPixel ); // error: invalid operands to binary expression
```

...I get an `invalid operands to binary expression` error.  I have also tried `inline`ing the `<` function outside of the struct, but I then get an error that the function cannot be defined here (within the method of the class).

In case it helps, here is a bigger picture of what I am trying to do.  I would like to store a list of pixels in an image (both their indices and their values).  I would like to be able to quickly find the pixel with the minimum value, and retrieve the index of that pixel.  After some reading, it seemed that a set containing a struct that held index and value and which could be compared based on the value, would be the most efficient option.  I have previously gotten the functionality I need by maintaining `vector`s of indices and values, and using `find` and `min_element`, but I have run into efficiency problems as the vectors get too large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator needs to be constant, so that it can be applied to the constant elements of a set:

```
bool operator <(const PixType&rhs) const
                                   ^^^^^
```

Alternatively, you could implement it as a non-member:

```
bool operator <(const PixType&lhs, const PixType&rhs)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that seems to have done it!  (Can't accept an answer for 3 minutes...)